# Replace random youtube link in text to embed code using javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, url, search, replace

I have some HTML code - for example:

```
<div>Text</div> 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZ2ekuCu4gM&feature=relmfu 
<div>Text</div> 
youtube.com/watch?v=adrJx864olE&feature=g-logo-xit
<div>Text</div>
<a href="#">LINK</a>
```

I need to automatically replace any YouTube URLs with iframes that embed the video at that URL, like the following:

```
<div>Text</div> 
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QZ2ekuCu4gM" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div>Text</div> 
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/adrJx864olE" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div>Text</div>
<a href="#">LINK</a>
```

How can I search the HTML code for a link from YouTube and replace it with  the equivalent iframe code using JavaScript?

Comment: I read the html text from the database and I want to do the following rewrite using javascript on client side.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
function linkYT(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var children = el.childNodes,
            text = [];
        for (var i=0, len=children.length; i<len; i++){
            var cur = children[i],
                nType = cur.nodeType,
                content = cur.nodeValue,
                url = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/';
            if (nType == 3 && content.indexOf('youtube.com') > -1) {
                var embed = content.trim().match(/v=(\w+)/)[1],
                    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.src = url + embed;
                el.insertBefore(iframe, cur.nextSibling);
                cur.parentNode.removeChild(cur);
            }
        }
    }
}

var el = document.getElementById('content');
linkYT(el);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jKA53/).

Please be aware there is ***no*** sanity-checking at all, and this approach requires that the video's identifier is prefaced with `v=` and terminated with a non-alphanumeric character.

I've tested and verified only in Opera 12, and Chromium 19.

To account for *one* other form of YouTube URL format:

```
function createIframe(embed, parent, after, url){
    if (!embed || !parent || !after) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        url = url ? url : 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/';
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = url + embed;
        parent.insertBefore(iframe, after.nextSibling);
        parent.removeChild(after);
    }
}

function linkYT(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var children = el.childNodes,
            text = [];
        for (var i=0, len=children.length; i<len; i++){
            var cur = children[i],
                nType = cur.nodeType,
                content = cur.nodeValue,
                url = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/';
            if (nType == 3) {
                if (content.indexOf('youtube.com') > -1) {
                    var embed = content.trim().match(/v=(\w+)/)[1];
                    createIframe(embed, el, cur);
                }
                else if (content.indexOf('youtu.be') > -1) {
                    var embed = content.trim().match(/be\/(\w+)/)[1];
                    createIframe(embed, el, cur);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var el = document.getElementById('content');
linkYT(el);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jKA53/3/).

Effectively it's the same process, just with a slightly different Regular Expression.

Because there's two places in which the `nodeType` must be found equal to `3` *and* two places in which `iframe`s are being created, I've wrapped the two `indexOf()` assessments inside of an `if` to test for the `nodeType` and abstracted `iframe`-creation to a separate function, both of which to simply avoid needless repetition.

References:

- [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/childNodes).
- [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore).
- [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nextSibling).
- [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeType).
- [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeValue).
- [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/parentNode).
- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild).
- [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Comment: David i have a problem. I read the data using ajax into a div and now isn't work. :( I have an empty div: <div id="Content"></div> How can i modify your solution?

Comment: Did you call the function again, after the Ajax content had loaded? The function will only run once, not continually and, if new content is added, the function must be called to parse that content.

Comment: Url is inside the html code - it is a problem. How do I fix this? Help me please David. :-)

Comment: I'd love to; I'm stuck in your demo though, since there's only one element being appended to the page, with no text. What's meant to be happening?

Comment: As far as I can see, this *should* work, and does in my [(perhaps limited) demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jKA53/6/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply David. I neet to replace this content: http://jsfiddle.net/F96ZK/1/ - Check please following link.